# How to convert a deep multi dimensional array to a single dimensional array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, flatten

I have a huge multi-dimensional array that i want to convert into a single dimensional array, the real issue is the array is dynamic and it can be a deep as it want to be and i am not sure about it in advance. Posting an example here

```
    var myArray =   [
        "hello", 
        ["berries", "grouped", 88, "frozen"], 
        [
            "stuff", 
            [
                "mash", 
                ["melon", "freeze", 12, "together"], 
                "people"
            ], 
            "car"
        ], 
        [
            "orange", 
            "code", 
            84, 
            ["mate", "women", "man"]
        ], 
        ["bus", "car", 345, "lorry"], 
        "world"
    ];
```

It should be converted to a single dimensional array like

```
["hello","berries","grouped",88,"frozen","stuff","....."]
```

Comment: How should the solution look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a walker function:

```
function walkLeaves(arr, fn)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        if (typeof arr[i] == 'object' && arr[i].length) { // simple array check
            walkLeaves(arr[i], fn);
        } else {
            fn(arr[i], i); // only collect leaves
        }
    }
}
```

And then use that to build the final array:

```
var final = [];
walkLeaves(arr, function(item, index) {
    final.push(item);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/nayuwejo/1/)

Answer (score 5):

Just try with:

```
var flat = myArray.join().split(',');
```

Output:

```
["hello", "berries", "grouped", "88", "frozen", "stuff", "mash", "melon", "freeze", "12", "together", "people", "car", "orange", "code", "84", "mate", "women", "man", "bus", "car", "345", "lorry", "world"]
```

Comment: How can i be such a fool.. awesome

Comment: But this isn't bullet-proof, because the content might contain commas

Comment: It also changes the items to strings, i.e. `int(88)` became `string("88")`

Comment: I feel jack's answer is the best one, and finally it makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Not a pure JavaScript solution but you could use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#flatten):

```
_.flatten(myArray)
```

...and [this is how they do it](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-49):

```
  var flatten = function(input, shallow, output) {
    if (shallow && _.every(input, _.isArray)) {
      return concat.apply(output, input);
    }
    each(input, function(value) {
      if (_.isArray(value) || _.isArguments(value)) {
        shallow ? push.apply(output, value) : flatten(value, shallow, output);
      } else {
        output.push(value);
      }
    });
    return output;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Normal looping + recursion:

```
var flattened = [];
function flatten(a){
    a.forEach(function(e){
       if(toString.call(e) === "[object Array]") flatten(e);
       else flattened.push(e);
    });
}

flatten(myArray);
```